# Output Texture is not coming from the code

Tags: opengl

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in given code, cause I am not getting any texture

```
float pixels[] = {
0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};
GLint texture;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
```

Comment: You are doing things out-of-order :)

Answer (score 0):

`glTexImage2D (...)` supplies texture image data to the currently bound texture name. The problem with your code is that you are uploading the texture image data before generating and binding your texture name (`texture`).

The solution is quite simple:

```c
/* Use a GLuint for OpenGL handles by the way */
GLuint texture;

glGenTextures (1, &texture);
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

/* After creating a texture name, and binding it, you have a valid context for
 *   the following API call.
 */
glTexImage2D  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

---

For faster image uploads, you should consider using an integer-based data type to store your data in the C code. When you create a `GL_RGB` texture, OpenGL is usually going to create a texture that uses 8-bit fixed-point per-channel, and `glTexImage2D (...)` does pixel data conversion when the image data is uploaded. This is known as pixel transfer conversion, and it increases driver overhead for things like `glReadPixels (...)` and `glTexImage2D (...)` when you use an internal format and pixel transfer format with different channel layout or basic data type.

Newer versions of OpenGL even let you specify the exact format to use internally, so if you want to guarantee 8-bit fixed-point, you could use `GL_RGB8` for the internal format. Coupling this with `GL_RGB` and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the pixel transfer will put you on the "fast path", and also make your code more portable between OpenGL and OpenGL ES (which does not allow pixel transfer conversion).

It is also worth mentioning that RGB8 is not a good choice of formats in the first place, the driver will almost certainly pad this out to RGBx8 to satisfy power-of-two alignment requirements on the hardware. Since you wind up with an extra 8-bits of unusable storage, RGBA8 works out better in the end and makes it clearer that you are not saving any memory by using an RGB image format. There are only a handful of 3-channel formats (`GL_R11F_G11F_B10F​` for instance) that actually use the same amount of storage as the sum of their components, 1-, 2- and 4-channel image formats are generally the way to go.